# How to detect file format in vim automatically?

Tags: vim

Though `set ff?` detects a fileformat manually, I don't know how to detect on startup.

I tried `if ($ff=='unix')` but it didn't.

So, is there a better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to read an option, you should use `&ff`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kent said, it's indeed `&ff`. But be aware of one thing, this only applies to the current buffer. If you open another file (`:e`, `:sp`...), it'll come with its own value.

A `.vimrc` is not the best place to analyze the file vim is opened with as it just do that: analyze this only file and react once only.

What are you trying to achieve exactly? (-> delete ^M if fileformat=unix)

EDIT: 
OK. Then, you need to listen for the `BufWritePre` event to fix the file on saving, or `BufReadPost` to fix it as soon as you read it. In that case, you may experience troubles with unmodifiable files, and you'll also have to play with `&modifiable`.

```
aug fix_eol
  au!
  BufReadPost * if &ff!=unix | keepp %s/\r$//e | endif
aug END
```

In all cases, the test shall not be plainly written in the `.vimrc`. These four lines can.

Comment: I guess he wants to write some autocmd.

Comment: I was trying to delete carriage return if fileformat was unix.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17378397)

Comment: @ScottHunter & reviewers. In my definition, anticipating future bugs/misbehaviours is not not-answering a question.